# Remove texts from an array of strings and check if a specific string contains in the array of strings?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL to Unity. The data is in the format of `ID:AZ22; ID:TR56;...`. I am able to fetch the data. But, I want to remove the text `ID:` from the array of data strings and finally I want to check if a particular string from Unity contains in the array of data strings. I am trying to use `Contains()` function but it does not seem to work. It does not matter for me if the string is found at 5th position or not at all. I just want the code to check if there is a match or not.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class ReceiveData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string checkForString = "AZ22";
    public string[] Items;
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        WWW data = new WWW("http://localhost/GetID.php");
        yield return data;
        string dataString = data.text;

        Items = dataString.Split(';');

        if(checkForString.Contains(dataString))
        {
            Debug.Log("String Contains");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("String does not contain");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to go the other way round: `dataString.Contains(checkForString)`?

Comment: I thought both works in similar manner right?

Comment: No ... Absolutely not. Let's say your downloaded text is e.g. `ID: AZ22` then `checkForString.Contains(dataString)` (== `"AZ22".Contains("ID: AZ22")`) will be **false** while `dataString.Contains(checkForString)` (== `"ID: AZ22".Contains("AZ22")`) will be **true**! Only the shorter text can be contained within the longer one .. not the other way round! Makes sense if you think about what "Contains" means ;)

Comment: @derHugo Oh okay Thanks! I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Items` is an array of strings of the form

```cs
{
    "ID:AZ22",
    "ID:TR56",
    ...
}
```

The method

```cs
Items.Contains(checkForString)
```

checks if the array `Items` contains the string `checkForString`, i.e. each item is compared whether it is **equal to** `checkForString`. Since the strings in items all contain the `"ID:"` part, none of the strings equals `"AZ22"`. You can solve this by comparing the entries with `"ID:AZ22"` - if you'd like to keep the id as is in your code, this would be possible with

```cs
Items.Contains($"ID:{checkForString}")
```

You could - however - strip the `"ID:"` right away with

```cs
Items = dataString.Split(';')
                  .Select(s => s.Substring(3))
                  .ToArray();
```

Of course, you don't have to add the `"ID:"` to `Contains` in this case.

#### Edit: For handling invalid input

If you get the error

> `startIndex` cannot be larger than length of string.

it means that any of the strings in the array does not have the form `"ID:XXXXX"`. In this case, you can filter the items before stripping the prefix

```cs
Items = dataString.Split(';')
                  .Where(IsValidId)
                  .Select(s => s.Substring(3))
                  .ToArray();
```

with

```cs
private bool IsValidId(string s)
{
    return s.StartsWith("ID:") && s.Length > 3;
}
```

The issue might also be, that the original string ends with `;`. In this case, `Split` returns an empty string as the last item. This can be mitigated by using `StringSplitOptions`

```cs
Items = dataString.Split(new[]{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Select(s => s.Substring(3))
                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. However, can I just remove ```ID:``` from the array of ```Items``` and then check it later? Or will it be expensive to do that? It is because I want to print all IDs later without the text ```ID:```.

Comment: @saif if it is necessary to do, (remove ID part) try the following before comparison: `Items = Items.Select(item => item.Replace("ID:",string.Empty));`

Comment: @elvira.genkel Thanks for your input, I had the edit window open already and added a portion similar to your suggestion. Please note that this won't work, since `Items` is an array and `Select` returns an `IEnumerable`, which is not assignable to the array.

Comment: @PaulKertscher I am getting an error as - ```'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found```.

Comment: @Saif you will need `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file. If using Linq anyway you could also simply check for `if(Items.Any(item => item.Contains(checkForString)))`

Comment: You have to add `using System.Linq;` to your usings.

Comment: @PaulKertscher I am using that but I guess mine is character rather than a string since I am getting an error ```Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char[]>' to 'string[]'```

Comment: maybe I should alter it to use ```c.ToString()```?

Comment: @Saif I guess that you wrote `Select(s => s.SubString(3).ToArray())`, instead of `Select(s => s.SubString(3)).ToArray()` watch the position of the brackets.

Comment: @PaulKertscher No it was something else. I fixed that but i guess there is still a bigger issue with that one line of code. ```startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
```

Comment: If `startIndex` is bigger than the longth of the string, the issue is, that not all of your entries follow the form `ID:XXXXX`, or at least miss the part behind the colon.

Comment: But all entries start the format with ```ID:``` if there is a way to remove only the first 3 strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209139/discussion-between-paul-kertscher-and-saif).